# X.org: two 'Screens' on one 'Device'

Tags: xorg

**Gentoo, linux 3.7.10

X.Org X Server 1.13.4

GDM 2.20.11

GNOME 2.32.1

Radeon HD 6850 card, radeon xorg driver**

I have Radeon HD 6850 card with two DVI monitors on it. `X -configure` command has generated `xorg.conf` file with which I see mirrored desktop on both monitors. If I go to *System->Preferences->Monitors* and reset *Same image in all monitors* flag then the desktop extends on both monitors.

This is almost what I want, but there is still one problem. If I maximise a window it spreads on **both** monitors and looks ugly. **How do I change it?**

I had idea that if I changed xorg settings a little and made it have two 'Screen' sections (per each monitor) then GDM would think there are two different screens and will create two different desktops. But xorg seems to ignore my settings (although the log file shows that there is no error and my configuration is accepted). Xrandr also says there are only one screen.

```
**xorg.conf**

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/misc/"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "nec_ea191m"
    VendorName   "NEC"
    ModelName    "EA191M"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "syncmaster_940n"
    VendorName   "Samsung"
    ModelName    "Syncmaster 940N"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "acer_v233h"
    VendorName   "Acer"
    ModelName    "V233H"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelDFS"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "IgnoreEDID"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorTiling"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorTiling2D"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "RenderAccel"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TVStandard"            # <str>
        #Option     "EXAVSync"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EXAPixmaps"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "ati_hd6850"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-0" "acer_233h"
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-1"     "nec_ea191m"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Throttle"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "DelayedFlush"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "intel_hd2000"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option      "Monitor-VGA1"  "syncmaster_940n"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "ati_hd6850"
    #Monitor    "nec_ea191m"
    Monitor    "acer_v233h"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "intel_hd2000"
    Monitor    "syncmaster_940n"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "ati_hd6850"
    Monitor    "nec_ea191m"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**A piece of Xorg.0.log**

```
[   191.201] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu May  2 17:38:33 2013
[   191.201] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   191.201] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   191.202] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[   191.202] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Monitor "acer_v233h"
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Device "ati_hd6850"
[   191.202] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Monitor "syncmaster_940n"
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Device "intel_hd2000"
[   191.202] (**) |-->Screen "Screen2" (2)
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Monitor "nec_ea191m"
[   191.202] (**) |   |-->Device "ati_hd6850"
[   191.202] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   191.202] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   191.202] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   191.202] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   191.202] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
```

**BTW, in fact I have two video cards and three monitors. But the problem concerns only Radeon adapter.**

Comment: First of all, do you really need a `xorg.conf` ? It's not so useful nowadays, especially if you use xorg drivers... You should try configure your display using `xrandr`.

Comment: I haven't done this with AMD cards successfully, but I have used Nvidia's TwinView to get two separate x screens

Comment: @lgeorget But I thought `xrandr` was just a front-end to X.org. I mean I know that with it you can change settings of X.org "on the fly". But I need permanent changes...

Comment: @krokoziabla you can do that in your `.xinitrc` for example